# Problem with add_rewrite_rule

Tags: url-rewriting

Been trying to re-map the following

```
/test-sale-yacht/comfortably-numb-262749/
/test-sale-yacht/?yacht_name_id=comfortably-numb-262749
```

After some testing in a regular expression tester I've put the following command in the init routine of the new plugin

```php
add_rewrite_rule('test-sale-yacht/([^/]*)?', 'index.php?name=test-sale-yacht&yacht_name_id=$1', 'top');
```

This looks similar to others so i figure it should work

I reset the permalinks several times by going to settings > permalinks and hitting save still does not work.

Tried putting it in `functions.php` in the theme, still no soap.

According to a debug plugin there are no rules getting hits on the page.

tried `/test-sale-yacht/?yacht_name_id=comfortably-numb-262749`, that works
tried `/?name=test-sale-yacht&yacht_name_id=comfortably-numb-262749`, that works
but `/test-sale-yacht/comfortably-numb-262749/`, nothing.

Totally foxed on this.

Jules

Comment: Note that if you get your rewrite rule working you'll still need to filter the permalinks on the links, WP won't auto-adjust them. Which debug plugin are you using? Have you tried monkeyman rewrite rules?

Comment: So I have to do more than declare the the er-write rule using add_rewrite_rule, I need to do something else as well before /test-sale-yacht/comfortably-numb-262749/ will be re-written?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to monkeyman

Comment: The rule is not showing up at all :(

Comment: Can you add more context to the code? It's literally just the call to `add_rewrite_rule` with no context, I can't tell how it's being called or when or on what hook

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell I have tried calling this in the plugin init routine and the functions.php, neither seem to work

Comment: Well its semi-working now, insists on doing a re-direct and ends up at /test-sale-yacht/

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the WP `$matches[1]` syntax for the regex that gets matched.

I think you want `/?` on the end too.

Easiest way I found to test was to temporarily put `flush_rewrite_rules()` in whilst testing, then you don't have to do anything else. I have a similar regex which sends `/foo/catname/` to `index.php?taxonomy=category&term=catname`, here's what I used to develop on a clean test WP install - this is working fine for me.

```
function foobar() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^foo/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?taxonomy=category&term=$matches[1]', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'foobar', 10, 0);
```

So you might want to try:

```
add_rewrite_rule('test-sale-yacht/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?name=test-sale-yacht&yacht_name_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Edit: As per comment by @Tom J Nowell, flush_rewrite_rules is an expensive call -  my suggestion to do this only on a dev or very low traffic site.

Comment: I would advise against calling `flush_rewrite_rules` on the `init` hook, it's extremely slow/expensive. It's enough to visit the permalinks setting page to flush permalinks

Answer (score 0):

This worked in the end, not sure why I was not getting anything showing up in the re-write rules initially but this worked.

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'test-sale-yacht/([^/]*)?', 
    'index.php?pagename=test-sale-yacht&yacht_name_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

with `yacht_name_id` added in as a filter

Jules